The source of random information in physics
In computer science, we can use the heat of a gas (or radiation, for example) to generate random noise. From them we can get a lot of random information. However, the question arises, where does this information come from in this gas? We believe that the source of this information in the gas is entropy and in a closed system it should not decrease with time. Suppose we have a box in which there is a set of orderly moving gas molecules (suppose they move like athletes in synchronized swimming, their speeds are the same and coordinates are tied to each other). Obviously such a system can be described using much less information than if it were a random gas. What prevents these molecules from elastically repelling each other and remaining the same ordered set for a long time?

"What prevents these molecules from elastically repelling each other and remaining the same ordered set for a long time?" Have you heard of something called a "solid?"

Or really any long range order? Maybe a "plasma oscillation" is what you are looking for?

I want to understand why, in a closed system, the information needed to describe it may increase over time. Where does this information come from if it did not exist before and we believe that the system is deterministic (classical mechanics)?

To give an example, in a deterministic cellular automaton, the state of the system at each instant of time can be described by initial conditions and current time, the amount of information in which may be very small.

Accordingly, the question arises, in classical mechanics, can the amount of information about the description of the system increase because more space is needed to store the time variable with each new iteration of its dynamics? Or some other reasons?

@J.Doe This information comes from the fact that no molecules are truly synchronized in a gas, so if some of them are synchronized by chance or specifically made a setup for it,- it will get de-synchronized more and more over time. So to defined additional desynchronization, you need additional information, that's obvious as two swimmers decouples- you need a pair of velocities and a pair of coordinates instead of one. "Desynchronization" is best illustrated with gas diffusion experiment,- setup ("synchronize") a box with 2 different gases with wall in-between. Remove wall and see what happens

The gas is a deterministic system too, only we don't know the initial conditions, and even if we did, we couldn't practically solve for the time evolution. So we coarse grain and give up information, and the amount of information we have to give up grows over time (if the system is not already in equilibrium).

For one, thermodynamic entropy and information entropy are not the same thing - e.g., see Is information entropy the same as thermodynamic entropy?. Also, when it comes to information entropy - the difference between information/negentropy/entropy is a matter of its usefulness.
